# How to create a string of vector names in R that will then be able to be evaluated?

Tags: r

In R, I currently have 100 dataframes, named `df.1`, ...,`df.100`. I would like to be able to `rbind` them but it is costly to write out:

```
rbind(df.1, df.2, etc)
```

So, I have tried:

```
rbind(eval(as.symbol(paste0("df.",1:84, collapse = ", "))))
```

However, this returns errors. Does anyone know how I can make the dataframes usable? thanks.

Comment: If you have any control over how these 100 dataframes are created in the first place, it's probably much easier to read them into a `list()` in the first place so you can access them using `df_list[["df1"]]`.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend reading [How do I make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `rbind` them one at a time in a loop.

```
df.1 = iris
df.2 = iris
df.3 = iris

DF = df.1
for(i in 2:3) {
    DF = rbind(DF, eval(as.symbol(paste("df", i, sep=".")))) }
```

Comment: did this need to be passed back into `DF` or does `rbind` concurrently save it?

Comment: You are right. Need to store back in DF.  Correcting answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `mget` and then `do.call` or `dplyr`'s `bind_rows` should work.

```
df.1 = iris[1:20,]
df.2 = iris[21:50,]

do.call("rbind",mget(paste0("df.",1:2)))

library(dplyr)
bind_rows(mget(paste0("df.",1:2)))
```

Comment: It seems that the `do.call` function gives rownames that do not match. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @user321627 - rownames that don't match what? They are equivalent to `datasetname.rownumber`, presumably so you can match back to the original datasets if need be.